# LaTeX created pdf is causing trouble while printing

Tags: printing, pdf

I need to have my thesis printed (131 pages front and back, 22MB size). It has several complex figures where you can literally watch how they are "created" when going to the respective pdf-page where they are located. Although there is no such figure at page 66, the printer (at 2 professional printing offices) stop printing there. I read that it might have something to do with insufficient computer memory among other reasons, but did not find a solution that could be easily implemented in a professional printing office. How can this problem be solved?

Comment: If it's a *professional* printing office it should have no problems. Choose a different printing house.

Comment: Too complex PDF program to paint the image. Simplify it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will assume for this answer that the complex figures are vector images that you have included with `\includegraphics`.  I will further assume that these vector images have many drawn entities, for example, a line plot with millions of line segments.

If all that is true, then you can ease the burden on the PDF viewer/printer by converting those vector images to raster before including them in your thesis.  You can do this using a graphics converter such as [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) or by doing a screen capture of the image from a PDF viewer.

Comment: Thank you. Exporting the figure to `PNG` instead of `PDF` solfed the problem.

Comment: @Lucas: [Please do not forget to accept the answer.](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/6865)

Comment: Thought I did it with the metal feather, sorry. Thx.

Comment: This will reduce the printing quality.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: Wouldn't that depend on the raster file resolution?  It is being converted to raster when sent to the printer anyway, right?

Comment: @James: Of course, if you raster at the printer's resolution, then you probably have no quality loss. But that should be done by the printer, since it knows best.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: I agree with you in the general case.  I certainly keep everything in vector format when possible.

Comment: @Lucas --- A free utility called [polygone](http://pcwww.liv.ac.uk/~itho17/personal/polygone/index.htm) can sometimes reduce the size of vector images without rasterizing or otherwise reducing quality.